# How to get server jwt from NSHTTPCookies in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, alamofire, jwt

I've got reponse cookies from server using Alamofire. My code is below :

```
    let urlPath :String = LOGIN_URL

    Alamofire.request(.POST, urlPath, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in

        print(response)

        if let
            headerFields = response.response?.allHeaderFields as? [String: String],
            URL = response.request?.URL
        {
            let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(headerFields, forURL: URL)
            print(cookies)

        }
    }
```

The line 9 : print(cookies) outputs :

[NSHTTPCookie

**version**:0

**name**:"X-Access-Token" **value**:"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.cb8mYjS5pNq2mqFS-yg3Orfuz_fYpWEaL3Pls0AsTaQ"

**expiresDate**:2016-06-13 06:24:56 +0000 **created**:2016-06-13 06:04:56 +0000 **sessionOnly:FALSE** **domain**:"mydomain.com" **path**:"/" isSecure:FALSE>]

here, the value is my expected jwt sent from server.

But it cant be accessed like cookies.value or cookies["value"].
So, to decode jwt How can I access **value** ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I've Solved the problem.

I need to get the cookies as NSObject and then extract value from it.

```
   let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(headerFields, forURL: URL) as NSObject
   let jwtfromCookie = (cookies.valueForKey("value"))!
   print(jwtfromCookie)
```